# I want to build a flight simulator!

Tags: flight-simulator

For fun I want to **build a flight simulator** at home.

What are my options from most basic toy environment to more realistic set-up.
Great if you can give for each solution a basic indication of cost (software / hardware), and if appropriate the space needed.

Comment: I've just started building a home cockpit too. I think this question is too broad, but here are the links I've bookmarked - they should give you a good starting point: 1) http://www.simprojects.nl/toggle_to_momentary.htm 2) http://home.planet.nl/~schre010/fs/toggle.html
3) http://www.flightsim.com/vbfs/content.php?2178 4)
http://youtu.be/49gZlRIUer0 Also, [my questions](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/36617/danny-beckett?tab=questions) on Electronics.SE might help you.

Comment: There's got to be an electronics/programming forum that would be better for this.  I think this StackExchange would be helpful when you get the pieces and are trying to make the simulator more realistic, but as for knowing where to buy and how much things cost...  No idea.  Perhaps this could give you an indication? http://www.redbirdflightsimulations.com/

Comment: Start with: http://www.sportys.com/Pilotshop/category/2238

If you just want to buy a ready-made setup, look at http://www.sportys.com/Pilotshop/product/19371

Comment: If you could make the question a little less broad, it would be great!

Comment: @JayCarr You mean like [Electronics.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com)? ;)

Comment: @DannyBeckett certainly seems more suited in my mind...